# how to make a html lightbox responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've created a lightbox gallery with html and css. I've to use the lightbox in a html website. when i add the lightbox code to my website it becomes non-responsive. both the gallery and lightbox should be responsive. what i have to do to make these lightboxes responsive.

```html
<section id="gallery">
    <!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link -->
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img1">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img2">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img3">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
</section>

<section id="gallery">
    <!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link -->
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img4">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img5">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img6">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
</section>

<!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
<div class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="#">hello</a></p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img3">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img2">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>    
    
<div class="lightbox" id="img2">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img2">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img3">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="lightbox" id="img3">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img2">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img1">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<a href="#">hello</a></p>
        
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img3">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img2">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>    
    
<div class="lightbox" id="img2">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img2">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img3">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="lightbox" id="img3">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img2">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img1">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>  


<style>

body {
    
    font-size:22px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #0f0f0f;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }


h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0f0f0f;
}   

h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0f0f0f;
}

h3 a {
    color: #0f0f0f;
}

a {
    color: #0f0f0f;
}
h1 {margin-top: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:60px;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
    }

p {
    text-align: center;
}   

#gallery {
    width:720px;
    margin:100px auto;
    }

#gallery a {
    text-decoration:none;
    }

#gallery .item {
    width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
    margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    }


#gallery .item a { 
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#gallery .item a img {
    height: 100%; 
    align-self: center;
    }

.lightbox {
    /** Hide the lightbox */
    width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
    
    /** Apply basic lightbox styling */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:#333333;
    transition: width .5s ease-in-out, height .5s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }

/** Show lightbox when it is target */
.lightbox:target {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    transition: width .5s ease-in-out, height .5s ease-in-out;
}

.lightbox .box {
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    min-width:500px;
    margin: 2% auto;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 26px -3px #777777; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
    }

.lightbox .title {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px #ccc solid;
    font-size:22px;
    }

.lightbox .content {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    }
    

.lightbox .content .desc {
    z-index:99;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 0 4px 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

    color:#fff;
    font-size:17px;
    opacity:0;
    text-align: left;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }   
    
.lightbox .content:hover .desc  {
    opacity:1;
}

.lightbox .next,
.lightbox .prev,
.lightbox .close {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#858585;
    }

.prev {
    float:left;
    }

.next, .close {
    float:right;
    }
    
.clear {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    }

.close_out {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

here is my code. what i've to change here to make them responsive. waiting for response.

Comment: Why is there a section tag with a `gallery` class inside the same class with a section tag?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put all the gallery items in 1 container.
2. Use `display: grid` to make it responsive. (I have added new class & css )

```html
<section class="gallery-container" id="gallery">
    <!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link -->
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img1">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img2">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img3">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
            <section class="item">
        <a href="#img4">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img5">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
        <a href="#img6">
          <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg">
        </a>
    </section>
</section>



<!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
<div class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="#">hello</a></p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img3">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img2">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>    
    
<div class="lightbox" id="img2">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img2">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img3">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="lightbox" id="img3">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img2">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img1">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<a href="#">hello</a></p>
        
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img3">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img2">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>    
    
<div class="lightbox" id="img2">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img2">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img3">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="lightbox" id="img3">
  <a class="close_out" href="#"></a>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://cbra.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/millet-guru.jpg"> 
        <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#img2">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#img1">Next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>  


<style>

body {
    
    font-size:22px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #0f0f0f;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }


h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0f0f0f;
}   

h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0f0f0f;
}

h3 a {
    color: #0f0f0f;
}

a {
    color: #0f0f0f;
}
h1 {margin-top: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:60px;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
    }

p {
    text-align: center;
}   

#gallery {
    width:720px;
    margin:100px auto;
    }

#gallery a {
    text-decoration:none;
    }

#gallery .item {
    width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
    margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    }


#gallery .item a { 
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#gallery .item a img {
    height: 100%; 
    align-self: center;
    }

.lightbox {
    /** Hide the lightbox */
    width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
    
    /** Apply basic lightbox styling */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:#333333;
    transition: width .5s ease-in-out, height .5s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }

/** Show lightbox when it is target */
.lightbox:target {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    transition: width .5s ease-in-out, height .5s ease-in-out;
}

.lightbox .box {
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    min-width:500px;
    margin: 2% auto;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 26px -3px #777777; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
    }

.lightbox .title {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px #ccc solid;
    font-size:22px;
    }

.lightbox .content {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    }
    

.lightbox .content .desc {
    z-index:99;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 0 4px 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

    color:#fff;
    font-size:17px;
    opacity:0;
    text-align: left;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }   
    
.lightbox .content:hover .desc  {
    opacity:1;
}

.lightbox .next,
.lightbox .prev,
.lightbox .close {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#858585;
    }

.prev {
    float:left;
    }

.next, .close {
    float:right;
    }
    
.clear {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    }

.close_out {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
 <!-- New CSS below  -->
.gallery-container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px, 1fr));
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the lightbox, elements positioned fixed would behave stupidly when given a `width:100%;`, I can't point to any docs for these claims though. Your best bet is to use

```
    .lightbox:target {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        /* Other codes */
    }
```

The above would stretch the lightbox to fill the viewport.

EDIT: am pretty sure the OP asked for the lightbox alone to be responsive.